# Why does Ubuntu complaint that my SD card is in use when it is not? How do I establish the connection to this device?

Tags: usb-drive, sd-card

My IOGEAR SD Card Reader/Writer is recognized on Ubuntu (by using VM ware) but when I try to connect to "Removable Devices -> Alcor Micro Flash Card Reader/Writer" , the following message appears:

```
The connection for the USB device "Alcor Micro Flash Card Reader/Writer" was unsuccessful.
The device is currently in use.
```

But I think it is not used. Should I use IOGEAR driver for this one? When I connect the card reader, Ubuntu automatically recognized the "Alcor Micro Flash Card Reader/Writer" .

How can I fix the problem?

```
$ lsusb

Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b95:7720 ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0e0f:0003 VMware, Inc. Virtual Mouse
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0e0f:0002 VMware, Inc. Virtual USB Hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0e0f:0008 VMware, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 0403:bcda Future Technology Devices International, Ltd
```

vmware log:

```
2013-10-18T09:00:07.494-06:00| vmx| I120: USB-CCID: Could not establish context: SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE(0x8010001d).
2013-10-18T09:00:07.494-06:00| vmx| I120: USB-CCID: Could not establish context: SCARD_E_NO_SERVICE(0x8010001d).
```

Comment: It was resolved by switching the USB slot. If you have the other solution/answer, I appreciate it.